# Infopath repeating table - Add new item

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

I guess this is simple, but I can't find out how to achieve this...

I want to have one row with controls in a table in InfoPath form, and button that says Add new item. When this button is clicked automatically a new row is created below the existing row with all the same controls.

I think that it has something with repeating tables...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeating section in Infopath provides this functionality by default. Where in repeating section you can add a table with controls in it. Have a look at [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/infopath-help/insert-a-repeating-table-HP010080916.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I tried the same before but when modifying the sharepoint list form in infopath, and the "Repeating table" & "Repeating section" controls weren't available. However on an infopath blank form it works perfectly. 
Thanks!!!